# Concerning the proof of divergence test for series

Tags: sequences-and-series

My teacher proved the divergence test as following : 
$$a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$$
If
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n-S_{n-1}=0$$
Then series may converge or diverge.

If
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n-S_{n-1}\ne0$$
Then series diverges.

**My question is :**

I just want to know whether I understand the meaning of the limit when it is zero or not zero : here is my understanding :

***when the limit is zero*** , it means that the sum is not changing as we add more terms .. which means that terms at infinity are equal to zero .. but it does not indicate whether the sum goes to infinity or not ( maybe by integral test we prove that the area under the curve goes to infinity just like the case of the simple harmonic series) , so if the limit is zero and the series diverges , the limit originally gives infinity minus infinity and after applying some operations it gives zero ..

***when the limit is not zero*** , it means that the sum of the series is alternating between 2 different values like 
$$\sum(-1)^n$$
or that the sum of the series is increasing and going to infinity ? ( in this case the limit will give infinity minus infinity which is indeterminate forms and after investigation , the limit gives value that is not zero)

**So concerning the following case:**
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n-S_{n-1}=\infty-\infty$$
I think in this case , the limit may be zero or not as I explained above..

Comment: When the limit is not zero, it could be any non-zero value, not just alternating.

Comment: Some examples of sequences with non-zero limits:
$$\begin{align}a_n &= \sin n\\a_n &= 1\\a_n &= \begin{cases}-1, &\text{if $n$ is prime}\\0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{align}$$
and so on.

Comment: You also wrote, "when the limit is zero, it means that the sum is not changing as we add more terms .. which means that terms at infinity are equal to zero". This is not precise language: first, which sum? Are you talking about $S_n$? Or the difference of sums $S_n - S_{n-1}$? Either way, they are likely changing as we add more terms, but just less and less. "Which means that terms at infinity are equal to zero"—there are no such things as "terms at infinity", which is why we have the concept of the limit.